# Платные расширения приложения

Tags: c#, плагин, mef

Здравствуйте.
Занят разработкой приложения. Планируется, что часть функционала приложения будет платной и после покупки будет подключаться к программе. Скажите, пожалуйста, подходит ли концепция плагинов в данном случае?
Если да, то стоит ли смотреть в сторону MEF?

Критерии пригодности технологии:

1. Легкость добавления дополнительных блоков программы.
2. Независимость блоков программы друг от друга.

Comment: а по каким критериям определять - подходит или нет?

Comment: Я пока не силен в архитектуре приложений. Слышал про концепцию плагинов - дополнений к программе. Также слышал, что для создания плагинов удобно использовать MEF. Мне интересно мнение опытных программистов. Может быть есть другие подходы и т. д.
Суть в следующем: необходимо, чтобы в программе был базовый функционал. Остальные опции, в том числе и элементы интерфейса должны подключаться после покупки.

Comment: Да, в принципе MEF вполне подходит. Если только вам не нужно чего-то реально сложного и необычного.

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет, "Очень воспитанный кролик")
Есть вопрос. Допустим у меня есть диагностический комплекс. Для разного типа устройств свои методы диагностики. Реально ли в такую программу добавлять плагины, в которых содержатся новые типы устройств и методы их диагностики?

Comment: @Eladei, если определишь общий интерфейс - вполне